# My app is only showing the background color of the scaffold and not the other contents until i click it once

Tags: android, flutter, cross-platform, mobile-development

I am working on an app using GetX as the state management. When i install the app and run it . It shows only the background color of the scaffold (which is black by default but to debug i changed it to blue. Then i get blue screen so i am confirm that it is the scaffold background color that i am seeing) and stays the same until i click on it once. When i click it. It starts working and shows the content of the scaffold body. What can be a possible solution?

I want the app to work without the need to be clicked once on the screen and it doesn't shows that static background color.

This is my main Function code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:semis/constants/pallete.dart';
import 'package:semis/features/auth/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:semis/features/child/screens/child_dashboard.dart';
import 'package:semis/features/school/screens/parent_school_dashboard.dart';
import 'package:semis/features/school/screens/select_school.dart';
import 'package:semis/features/school/screens/teacher_school_dashboard.dart';
import 'package:semis/splash_screen.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';


void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn');

  if (isLoggedIn == true) {
    runApp(const MyApp(isLoggedIn: true));
  } else {
    runApp(const MyApp());
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isLoggedIn;
  const MyApp({Key? key, this.isLoggedIn = false}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Pallete.blueColor,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.light,
    ));
    return GetMaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColor: Pallete.blueColor,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: isLoggedIn ? '/splash' : '/login',
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: '/login', page: () => const LoginScreen()),
        GetPage(name: '/splash', page: () => const SplashScreen()),
        GetPage(name: '/select-school', page: () => const SelectSchool()),
        GetPage(
            name: '/parent-school-dashboard',
            page: () => const ParentSchoolDashboard()),
        GetPage(
            name: '/teacher-school-dashboard',
            page: () => const TeacherSchoolDashboard()),
        GetPage(name: '/child-dashboard', page: () => const ChildDashboard()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code of the screen which have the issue.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'package:semis/constants/animated_loader.dart';
import 'package:semis/constants/pallete.dart';
import 'package:semis/features/auth/controllers/login_controller.dart';
import 'package:semis/features/school/screens/select_school.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final LoginController _authController = Get.put(LoginController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Pallete.blueColor,
        body: Obx(
          () => _authController.isLoading.value
              ? const AnimatedLoader()
              : SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        width: Get.width,
                        height: Get.height * 0.5,
                        child: Center(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 350,
                              width: 350,
                              child: Lottie.asset(
                                'assets/animations/login.json',
                                repeat: true,
                                reverse: true,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: Get.height * 0.5,
                        width: Get.width,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(40),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(40),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Form(
                          key: _formKey,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 30,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "SEMIS - School Education Management Information System",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                    fontSize: 23,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    color: Pallete.blueColor,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Opacity(
                                  opacity: 0.6,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "semis Serves You Virtual Education At Your Home",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      color: Pallete.blackColor,
                                      wordSpacing: 3,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 50,
                                ),
                                TextFormField(
                                  controller:
                                      _cnicController, // CNIC Input Field
                                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "CNIC",
                                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.credit_card),
                                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                  ),
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value!.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Please enter your CNIC';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  onPressed: () => _handleLogin(),
                                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                    backgroundColor: Pallete.blueColor,
                                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                    ),
                                    minimumSize: Size(Get.width, 50),
                                  ),
                                  child: const Text(
                                    "Log In",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                      wordSpacing: 2,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleLogin() async {
    try {
      _authController.isLoading.value = true; // Set loading state to true
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        // Form is valid, proceed with login
        final cnic = _cnicController.text;
        final schools = await _authController.cnicLogin(cnic);
        if (schools != null) {
          // Check if there are users associated with the CNIC
          if (schools.schoolCount > 0) {
            _saveLogin(cnic);
            Get.off(
              () => const SelectSchool(),
              arguments: {'schools': schools, 'cnic': cnic},
            );
          } else {
            // If no users found, display a message to the user
            Get.snackbar(
                "No Users Found", "No users are associated with this CNIC.");
          }
        }
      }
    } finally {
      _authController.isLoading.value = false;
    }
  }

  void _saveLogin(String cnic) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('cnic', cnic);
    await prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);
  }

  final TextEditingController _cnicController = TextEditingController();

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an onclicklistener set on the background of the scaffold that is responsible for showing the content of the scaffold when the background is clicked? You might want to check that the code responsible for initializing the state of the app and displaying the content of the scaffold is called in the right place and at the right time, this may be the initState or onCreateView callback

Comment: Yes I am using GestureDetector. I have added the code above. You can have a look.